# IBM Watson STT + MQTT weird behaviour

Tags: mqtt, speech-recognition, ibm-watson, speech-to-text, paho

I am working on remote transcription using Watson STT. I stream audio from a mic to an mqtt client that interfaces with watson stt via websocket.

Everything words fine if I follow this flow.

RECORD CHUNK -> RECORD CHUNK -> RECORD CHUNK -> PUBLISH CHUNK ->  PUBLISH CHUNK ->PUBLISH CHUNK

The only problem is that I have to wait until I finish recording to start transcribing, which is kind of slow.

To speed things up, I want to have the recognition happen while I am recording. So I followed this

RECORD CHUNK -> PUBLISH CHUNK ->RECORD CHUNK -> PUBLISH CHUNK ->RECORD CHUNK -> PUBLISH CHUNK ->RECORD CHUNK

When I do this I never get a final transcript from Watson STT. The only thing I can think of is that the latency between chunks is increased and Watson does not tolerate that?